# "Unexpected SeqBase<T> length" from matplotlib's backend_agg.py

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, cygwin, networkx

I'm trying to use *pylab* and *networkx*  to draw a directed-graph.

Below is a small demo script and the error it produces (and, the window created by pylab is empty).

Googling shows that this error was supposed to be fixed in mathplotlib's svn already in 2008.

**Anyone could point me in the right direction?**

This script:

```
import pylab
import networkx as nx

def Working_with_graphs_using_networkx():
    fig = pylab.figure()
    g = nx.Graph(name = "graph")
    pylab.title(g.name)
    g.add_node("John")
    g.add_node("Maria")
    g.add_edge("John", "Maria")
    pos = nx.spring_layout(g)
    nx.draw(g, pos)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Working_with_graphs_using_networkx()
    pylab.show()
```

Produces this error (on Python 2.6 under cygwin):

```
$ python demo_SeqBase.py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 236, in resize
    self.show()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 239, in draw
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 401, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 884, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py", line 1983, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 238, in draw
    self._linewidths, self._linestyles, self._antialiaseds, self._urls)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 84, in draw_path_collection
    return self._renderer.draw_path_collection(*kl, **kw)
IndexError: Unexpected SeqBase<T> length.
```

Comment: Since There are no solutions as yet, I took a different tack, and wrote the script using altgraph.Dot. (The resulting graph can be seen [here](http://ronbarak.tumblr.com/post/41095500427/how-a-tumblr-post-gets-reblogged-four-days-ago-i)).

Comment: what version of mpl are you using?  This code runs with out error for me (but python 2.7, mpl 1.3.x under linux).  That looks like an error coming out of the c++ extensions that handle wrapping Agg.  I suspect the fix is upgrade your mpl version.